# No overload for method 'Add' takes 3 arguments- Selenium C#

Tags: excel, csharpcodeprovider

```
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)pivotTableWorkBook.Worksheets.Item[1];

Range pivotData = ws.Range["A1:N82009"];
Range pivotDestination = ws.Range["Q4"];
string pivotTableName = "Call Cycle Pivot Table";
PivotCache pivotCache = pivotTableWorkBook.PivotCaches().Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, pivotData);
//PivotTable pivotTable = ws.PivotTables().Add(pivotTableName, pivotDestination, pivotCache);
PivotTable pivotTable = ws.PivotTables().Add( pivotTableName, pivotDestination, pivotCache);
```

I was creating a pivot table through Selenium Csharp, but suddenly I encountered this error. Tried a lot to fix it but failed. Please help me to solve this. The code which I shown above is Microsoft interop

Comment: What kind of code is this? VBA? Microsoft interop? Third party (such as EPPlus)?

Comment: looks like it takes 5 arguments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivottables.add?view=excel-pia#microsoft-office-interop-excel-pivottables-add(microsoft-office-interop-excel-pivotcache-system-object-system-object-system-object-system-object)

Comment: Can you please tell me what should be the remaining 2 arguments